# Resampling raster based on more than 16 nearest cells?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, resampling, smoothing, habitat-modeling

I have a habitat suitability map, with cells of 30x30, each with a score of relative suitability for fox. The problem is that, with 30x30 cells, the grain is too fine for getting a broad sense of what general areas are likely to support the species. Whether or not a region will be suitable will also depend on the suitability of the nearby cells, not just the immediate cell.

In trying to best represent this visually I think I need to do some sort of resampling to get the smoother effect I'm looking for. The issue though, is that the built in methods don't take into account enough of the neighbouring cells to accurate reflect the score. Cubic appears to take the average of the nearest 16 cells into account, but I'd like to incorporate more. I don't actually want to change cell size, just the values within. To that end, I'm not even sure that "resampling" is what I need.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: Will focal statistics work?

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP. Yes that actually looks like precisely what I'm looking for. Trying to run it now. Running into some issues with strange outputs, but I think I'm heading in the right direction now.